# set alertmanager to distribute alerts to different channel by job name

Tags: regex, prometheus, monitoring, prometheus-alertmanager

I want to send my alert to two different distribution lists in Alertmanager for Prometheus. The only way to distinguish my alerts is by their job name.

my alert names are like below:

sample1:

```
Labels
alertname = SyslogErrors
instance = 22.32.23.32:2324
job = my-job-sample-service-dev
message = Exception raised during message subscription. Trying again in 60 seconds
monitor = server1
severity = critical
Annotations
description = Errors have been found for my-job-sample-service-dev application in /data/logs/messages/my-job-sample-service-dev syslog file
Source
```

sample2:

```
Labels
alertname = SyslogErrors
instance = 22.32.23.32:2324
job = my-job-sample-service-pre-dev
message = Exception raised during message subscription. Trying again in 60 seconds
monitor = server1
severity = critical
Annotations
description = Errors have been found for my-job-sample-service-pre-dev application in /data/logs/messages/my-job-sample-service-pre-dev syslog file
Source
```

here is my sample alertmanager config file:

```
global:
  smtp_smarthost: 'mail.server.com:25'
  smtp_from: 'dev@server.com'
  smtp_require_tls: false
templates:
- '/etc/alertmanager/template/*.tmpl'
route:
  receiver: mail-receiver-dev
  group_by: ['alertname']
  group_wait: 3s
  group_interval: 5s
  repeat_interval: 1h
  # All alerts that do not match the following child routes
  # will remain at the root node and be dispatched to 'default-receiver'.
  routes:
  - receiver: 'mail-pre-dev'
    group_wait: 10s
    match_re: 
    - job = .*pre-dev.*
  - receiver: 'mail-dev'
    group_wait: 10s
    match_re:
    - job = .*dev.*

receivers:
- name: 'mail-dev'
  email_configs:
  - to: 'dev-group@server.com'
    send_resolved: true
- name: 'mail-pre-dev'
  email_configs:
  - to: 'pre-dev-group@server.com'
    send_resolved: true
```

I am using the below link as a reference:
[reference](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/)

[Testing config file link](https://prometheus.io/webtools/alerting/routing-tree-editor/)
testscript for using above link:  {service="foo-service",severity="critical",job="my-job-sample-service-dev"}

So the question is, how to send an alert to a different channel by using **regex** for the **job** title? At the moment when I test all the alert goes to pre-dev.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: my alert are not filtering properlu based on the match_re: 
    - job = .*pre-dev.*

when I try to test them all the message will go directly to pre-dev. I want to know how I can use regex to filter my alert based on the job title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following:

```
match_re: 
- job = .*pre-dev.*
```

To:

```
matchers: 
- job =~ ".*pre-dev.*"
```

Note:

"match_re" is deprecated and must be replaced by "matchers", but if you want to use it, the correct syntax is:

```
match_re:
- job: ".*pre-dev.*"
```

Comment: Thank you Marcelo, it works! can you add some explanation of when we should use this format? matchers: '{ XYZ}', because I tried the way u did but in this format and it didn't work. I saw it in the documentation.